# Layout issues in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, ios9

I have an app compatible with iOS 8 and iOS 9. In iOS 9 it works good but when I tried it in the simulator for iOS 8 there's a lot of layout issues (not just in one screen, in the whole app). I know it's really answer to predict without seeing the code but it's happening in a lot of places so I'm not sure how to debug it. Does anybody had this problem? Can someone give me an idea of where to start looking at? I re-did the view constraints again but without luck.

**ios 8 images on an iPhone 6**

[image: ios 8 example 1]

[image]

**Same views on iOS 9**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the warnings you get for layout when building on ios 8

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq should not fail the same way in all the iOS versions?

Comment: there have been a few changes in how the layout for a view is constructed in iOS9. Have a look at the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/) of iOS 9 especially the UIKit Section (I'm referring to the second note in this section)